# Neo4j - Getting a list of Post nodes in order of date posted

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've recently started sketching up a personal project which will involve a social network side. I have some professional experience with Neo4j and while it feels like a perfect match there is one query that concerns me.

Imagine a general social network: users follow each other, users post posts, users can see the posts written by the users they're following. This is cleanly expressed in Neo4j through `:User` and `:Post` labelled nodes, connected through `:posted` and `:follows` relationships.

So I could get the posts by users I follow using a query like:

```
MATCH (:User {user_id: 1})-[:follows]->(:User)-[:posted]->(p:Post)
RETURN p
```

This is pretty clean and simple. My concern is that realistically I will want to get the most recent 10 posts, and then the 10 posts after that, and so on.

So I created an index on a `created_at` field in `:Post` nodes and added an `ORDER BY p.created_at DESC` clause to the query. I thought this would allow me to sort them efficiently however running an `EXPLAIN` on this query shows that `ORDER BY` clauses do not, for the most part, use indexes to speed up this process. As such I'm unsure if there's a way to get these efficiently when the result set becomes significantly large.

This may be inexperience or just approaching this data model incorrectly. Can I get some input on this kind of problem? Should I model my data differently? Is my query/index wrong? Is there something I'm missing? How would you do this?

**EDIT 1:** Example query for something like what I meant:

```
MATCH (:User {user_id: 1})-[:follows]->(:User)-[:posted]->(p:Post)
RETURN p
ORDER BY p.created_at DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Also I've been thinking that using a range (in a `WHERE` clause) is a possibility to limit the result set size but still unsure of whether there's a better way?

**EDIT 2 (Solution):** This was the final query that made the Cypher planner use the index for this problem:

```
MATCH (:User {user_id: 1})-[:follows]->(:User)-[:posted]->(p:Post)
USING INDEX p:Post(created_at)
WHERE p.created_at < datetime()
RETURN p
ORDER BY p.created_at DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Can you show in your question the query that sorts the posts? Also, are you using neo4j 3.5+?

Comment: @cybersam I added an example query. This is all very hypothetical still and I'm only using an example data model. I am aware that there were improvements to index usage in order by in 3.5, however it's fairly limited and only available for ascending order (the opposite of what I need). If I missed something let me know!

Comment: It supports descending sorts as well. See my answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neo4j 3.5 introduced some [support for using indexes to perform `ORDER BY` operations](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/cypher-index-values-order/), with some restrictions.

But, currently (in neo4j 3.5.3), even when the usage of an index is supported for `ORDER BY`, the Cypher planner does not seem to automatically use it for that purpose. In my experimentation with version 3.5.3, I found that if you do not use the index in a `WHERE` clause then the planner will not use the index at all.

So, as a simple workaround, you can just add a trivial `WHERE` clause using the index. For example, here is a modified version of your query that will "trick" the planner into using the index for `ORDER BY`:

```
MATCH (:User {user_id: 1})-[:follows]->(:User)-[:posted]->(p:Post)
WHERE p.created_at > 0
RETURN p
ORDER BY p.created_at DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Profiling that query on a small dataset I generated still doesn't use the index (100 users, each user has 100 posts, tested on a user that follows all other 99 users - produces 48291 database hits in 68 ms). But I found that adding a `USING INDEX p:Post(created_at)` clause does make it use the index, generating only 227 database hits in 3 ms. A bit crazy how convoluted it is to get Neo4j to use indexes on these scenarios. Again, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.